# How to create a new column in a select query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, insert

In MS Access, I want to insert a new column into the returned result of a select query. The new column has the same value for every row. For example, my select returns columns A, B and I want C to be the new column created by the select query:

```
A   B   C
----------
a1  b1  c
a2  b2  c
a3  b3  c
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
select A, B, 'c' as C
from MyTable
```

Comment: Is there any reference for this?

Comment: can use case expression to set targeted value for field C.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT field1, 
       field2,
       'example' AS newfield
FROM TABLE1
```

This will add a column called "newfield" to the output, and its value will always be "example".

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you wanted to do with that column e.g. here's an example of appending a new column to a recordset which can be updated on the client side:

```
Sub MSDataShape_AddNewCol()

  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rs
    .ActiveConnection = _
    "Provider=MSDataShape;" & _
    "Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Tempo\New_Jet_DB.mdb"
    .Source = _
    "SHAPE {" & _
    " SELECT ExistingField" & _
    " FROM ExistingTable" & _
    " ORDER BY ExistingField" & _
    "} APPEND NEW adNumeric(5, 4) AS NewField"

    .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

    .Open

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To .RecordCount - 1
      .Fields("NewField").Value = Round(.Fields("ExistingField").Value, 4)
      .MoveNext
    Next

    rs.Save "C:\rs.xml", adPersistXML

  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'column_value' (replace column_value with actual value) AS column_name
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: You seem to have a tendency to post [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that have already been posted by someone else and where your answer contains code only with no explanation. If your answer contains something that does **not** already appear in any of the other answers, please enlighten me.